# how can i display a list of data by a user Id using flutter and firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

so basically every user has his own restaurants and i want to display them in a listview.builder by the user ID in firebase.
i named the user class myUser while the restaurants class's named Restaurants
this is my code :

```
class RestaurantsList extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _RestaurantsListState createState() => _RestaurantsListState();
}

class _RestaurantsListState extends State<RestaurantsList> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final restaurants = Provider.of<List<Restaurants>?>(context);
    final user = Provider.of<myUser?>(context);

    Future getRests() async{
      final RestauCollection = 
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('restaurants').doc(user?.uid).get();
      print('yassine');


      return RestauCollection ;
   }

      return Column(
      children: [
        CardsTemplateAddRestau(),
        new Expanded(

          child:FutureBuilder(
            future: getRests(),
            builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
              return new ListView.builder(

                  itemCount: snapshot.data.data()?.length,itemBuilder: (context,index)
              {
                   print(user?.fullName);
                return CardsTemplateRestau(restau:snapshot.data.data()?[index]);
              });
            },

          ),
        ),
      ],
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you currently having?

Comment: it returns null instead of the restaurants cards